# Find and save many to many mapping of 2 images in C# (2-D Arrays)

Tags: c#, image-processing

- I am doing a  C#  image processing WPF application.
- I want to compare 2 images' pixels based on their pixel values, and
  the comparison should be done like **M:N mapping** (many-to-many).

ie:

- image 1 has 10*10 pixels
- image 2 has 20*20 pixels
- Pixels from image 1 has to be compared with image 2. At the same time
  pixels from image 2 has to be compared with image 1 in-order to find
  the best matching pair-of-pixels. (comparison => pixel difference
  between those 2 pixels)
- I have already done one-to-one mapping. But later i found it is not
  finding the best pair of matching pixels. Hence i want to do
  many-to-many mapping of these 2 images.
- Please suggest an algorithm to do the comparison efficiently regarding exec time based on many-to-many mapping of pixels. And a way to save those comparisons and find best pair of matching pixels.

*

- *P.S : I'm using Image processing, openCV utilities for my project*

*